# C Programming Crash

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

For some reason, my program will crash with the error:

> 1 [main] Popular Names 6428 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to Popular Names.exe.stackdump

I am reading in a txt that has a list of names with the amount of people given that name within that particular year. (e.g. yob1920.txt = the names given to newborns in the year 1920). The big component is that I have to use pointers to pass 2D arrays that will hold the names and the popularity of each name.

My program first reads in the file, then reads a line, and when it reaches read_In_Line function, it will take the name of from that line and store it into a char array as a string.
(e.g. Mary,F,70980<- Only care about the "Mary")

From here, I want to store the name into the names 2D array only if it is not currently stored there already. Afterwords, I want to update the names popularity ranking in the ranks 2D array for that current year.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ROW 400
#define NAME_COL 50
#define RANK_COL 10
void read_In_Files(char **names, int **ranks);
void read_In_File(char **names, int **ranks, FILE *infile, int year);
void read_In_Line(char **names, int **ranks, char *line, int count, int year);
void sort_Array();
void create_Output();


int main(void) {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF,0);
    char names[ROW][NAME_COL]; //Holds strings of names
    int ranks[ROW][RANK_COL + 1]; //Hold popularity of names
    read_In_Files(names, ranks);

    return 0;
}

void read_In_Files(char **names, int **ranks) {
    FILE *infile1 = fopen("yob1920.txt","r"); //Opens file to be read
    read_In_File(names, ranks, infile1, 0); //Contains names 


}

void read_In_File(char **names, int **ranks, FILE *infile, int year) {
    int count = 0, i;
    char line[100000];

    while(count != 100) {
        fscanf(infile, "%s", line); //Grab a line from txt and store in line array
        read_In_Line(names, ranks, line, count, year);
        memset(line, '\0', sizeof(line)); //Clear line array
        count++; //Read only the first 100 lines
    }
}

void read_In_Line(char **names, int **ranks, char *line, int count, int year) {
    char temp;
    char save[30];
    int i = 0;
    while(1) { //Take only name from the line
        temp = line[i];
        if (isalpha(temp)) {
            save[i] = temp;
        } else {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < ROW; i++) { //Search names array for 
        if(strstr(names[i], save)) { //the current name stored in save array
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i == ROW - 1) { //If not found, add name
        for(i = 0; i < ROW; i++) { //Add to the end of the list
            if(names[i] == '\0') { //of names
                break;
            }
        }
        names[i] = save; //Adds name
    }

    ranks[i][year] = count; //Update popularity rank based on year of
                            //txt file and ranking in the file.
}

void sort_Array() { //Not implemented

}

void create_Output() { //Not implemented

}
```

Comment: Well, for starters, `char names[ROW][NAME_COL];` will **not** work as a parameter passed to a function expecting `char **`. Something has to change. Likewise for `ranks`. Whoever told you a pointer to pointer is synonymous an array of arrays was wrong, and if you compiler didn't at-least-*warn* you about this you need to turn up your warning level.

Comment: How are you developing? Do you use an IDE - with an integrated debugger? If you do, then you shouldn't need to ask here. Juts set a breakpoints, step through your code line by line, examine variable values .. and it should be quickly obvious what is going wrong.